# Use the value of a child of an object in an array to get the index of the said object

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array as such:

```
var maskedlist = [
  {id:-1,name:'*****选'},
  {id:0,name:'*****(3天)'},
  {id:1,name:'*****'},
  {id:3,name:'*****'},
  {id:2,name:'*****列'},
  {id:4,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:5,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:6,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:7,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:8,name:'*****'},
  {id:9,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:10,name:'*****铺系列'},
  {id:12,name:'*****列'},
  {id:11,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:13,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:14,name:'*****'},
  {id:15,name:'*****列'},
  {id:100,name:'*****部测试号'},
  {id:200,name:'*****厅体验版'},
  {id:201,name:'*****'},
  {id:202,name:'*****单店系列'},
  {id:203,name:'*****多店系列'},
  {id:16,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:17,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:204,name:'*****代运营套餐'},
  {id:205,name:'*****活动运营'},
  {id:206,name:'*****内容运营'},
  {id:207,name:'*****商户运营'},
  {id:208,name:'*****外卖系列'}
]
```

And I will have a variable `incoming_id` that will potentially match one of the obj's child id's value, let's say it is `205`.

So in the following new obj:

```
var entity = {
  selected: maskedlist[index]
}
```

Now how would I be able to get `index` from `incoming_id`?

Obviously I can use for loop like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < maskedlist.length; i++) {
  maskedlist[i].id == incoming_id && index = i
}
```

Doesn't feel very elegant tho, and if I have a list that is long enough it can be really slow and may crash the browser from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the index in array you can use [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

But according to your question it is better to use use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the object in the array `maskedlist` with the property `id` equal to `205`.

Code examples to find `index` and `entity`:

```js
var maskedlist = [{id: -1,name: '*****选'},{id: 0,name: '*****(3天)'},{id: 1,name: '*****'},{id: 3,name: '*****'},{id: 2,name: '*****列'},{id: 4,name: '*****系列'},{id: 5,name: '*****系列'},{id: 6,name: '*****系列'},{id: 7,name: '*****系列'},{id: 8,name: '*****'},{id: 9,name: '*****系列'},{id: 10,name: '*****铺系列'},{id: 12,name: '*****列'},{id: 11,name: '*****系列'},{id: 13,name: '*****系列'},{id: 14,name: '*****'},{id: 15,name: '*****列'},{id: 100,name: '*****部测试号'},{id: 200,name: '*****厅体验版'},{id: 201,name: '*****'},{id: 202,name: '*****单店系列'},{id: 203,name: '*****多店系列'},{id: 16,name: '*****系列'},{id: 17,name: '*****系列'},{id: 204,name: '*****代运营套餐'},{id: 205,name: '*****活动运营'},{id: 206,name: '*****内容运营'},{id: 207,name: '*****商户运营'},{id: 208,name: '*****外卖系列'}],
    index = maskedlist.findIndex(obj => obj.id === 205),
    entity = {
      selected: maskedlist.find(obj => obj.id === 205)
    };

console.log('index:', index);
console.log('entity:', entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
 let index='';
    maskedlist.some(function(o){if( o["key1"] === "value2"){index = 
    maskedlist.indexOf(o["key1"]) }})
```

will be true if pair is found, otherwise false.

This assumes each object contains only one key/value pair, and that the value is never undefined

Answer (score 0):

Better use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var maskedlist = [
  {id:-1,name:'*****选'},
  {id:0,name:'*****(3天)'},
  {id:1,name:'*****'},
  {id:3,name:'*****'},
  {id:2,name:'*****列'},
  {id:4,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:5,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:6,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:7,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:8,name:'*****'},
  {id:9,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:10,name:'*****铺系列'},
  {id:12,name:'*****列'},
  {id:11,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:13,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:14,name:'*****'},
  {id:15,name:'*****列'},
  {id:100,name:'*****部测试号'},
  {id:200,name:'*****厅体验版'},
  {id:201,name:'*****'},
  {id:202,name:'*****单店系列'},
  {id:203,name:'*****多店系列'},
  {id:16,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:17,name:'*****系列'},
  {id:204,name:'*****代运营套餐'},
  {id:205,name:'*****活动运营'},
  {id:206,name:'*****内容运营'},
  {id:207,name:'*****商户运营'},
  {id:208,name:'*****外卖系列'}
]

var entity = {}

entity.selected = maskedlist.find(item => item.id === 205)

console.log(entity)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
**array.find(function(currentValue, index, arr),thisValue)**

So, it would be something like:

```
var entity = {
   selected: maskedlist.find(function(obj) {
       return obj.id === incoming_id ;
    })
  };
```

Comment: This is not performant, because Array.prototype.filter() will go to the end of array `maskedlist` even when has been found the `obj.id`